# Opening modal conditionally in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material Dialog to open a modal. In the modal that opens, I have few components that every time a different one should be loaded based on a condition. The thing is, I tried to pass the `.open()` method the component name as a string, and it gives error.

For example, let's say this the method:

```
openDialog(): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
});
```

I tried to do something like:

```
let myComp: string = 'DialogOverviewExampleDialog'; 

openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.myComp, {
  width: '250px',
});
```

But it gives error. It just don't get a variable as a parameter to the function.

The reason I need to pass the name as a string, so I can create a condition, assign for each condition the component that should be open in the modal, then just pass the `.open()` method the variable with the name of the desire component to be load

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DialogOverviewExampleDialog is a class. So modify  your code to

```
let myComp: any = DialogOverviewExampleDialog; 

openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.myComp, {
  width: '250px',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let myComp : DialogOverviewExampleDialog
```